# Nested \( \) and group ()

Tags: minted, grouping, mathjax, parenthesis

I am trying to allow programmers using Felix to write some formulas in LaTeX, in such a way they compile correctly, display correctly online using MathJaX, and typeset correctly using pdflatex with minted environment. This is quite a challenge! View here a sample:

http://felix-lang.org/share/src/web/advocate/mathinfelix.fdoc

I cannot use { } for grouping as the meaning is otherwise. However () and \( \) are grouping (in Felix). I specify at the moment that typesetting treats both \( \) and ( ) as TeX groups, where \( \) is invisible, but ( ) is displayed.

My webserver translates this encoding correctly to MathJaX compatible LaTeX, but it would be nice if it didn't require translation. Writing the reference manual is a real pain because I have to do the translation manually.

In general, TeX and LaTeX just weren't designed for either programming languages, or advanced maths (that is, category theory). Translation is unavoidable in the web server to handle multi-character identifiers, even in maths hackery is required to get names like sin, cos, or tan to typeset.

Anyhow my question: is there a way to coerce LaTeX into accepting nested \( \), treating them in math mode like { }, and accepting ( and ) and treating them like {(  )}?

And related: can minted package by coerced into doing this as well?
(If not I can of course hack the Python but it seems non trivial).

Comment: First of all you need to specify what your question is about? Mathjax has nothing to do with latex and questions about it generally has to go elsewhere. It is a Javascript library that knows how to render a (big) part og latex' math syntax. But it dies not use latex in doing so. Thus any answer that apply to latex will not apply to mathjax.

Comment: Also for the reason mentioned above I'd recommend you also tag this with mathjax.

Comment: In LaTeX \( and \) start and stop an in-line math equation and therefore cannot be nested. They are NOT meant to be used instead of ( and ).

Comment: That should have been \\( and \\) in my comment above.

Comment: @HerbSchulz `\(…\)` *can* be nested, where it makes sense (e.g. in combination with `\text{}`)! — in fact, that’s part of the reason to prefer them to `$…$`. At any rate, you can always redefine them to be equivalent to `{…}`. It sounds like that’s what OP wants.

Comment: Yes, I believe I seek 1 or perhaps two sets of Tex/Latex commands which will allow Felix program code as written to be typeset (a) on the web and (b) in PDF documents. For (a) I currently use mathjax set so \\( \\) introduce mathmode and trigger mathjax, for PDF I use pdflatex with minted package but must use escapeinside option to escape to latex typesetting. With the webservice, my server translates Felix to Latex which mathjax can display. With latex I have to manually rewrite the code. I have hundreds of pages of book text. Rewriting example code is not desirable.

Comment: Saying that TeX and LaTeX were not designed to typeset advanced mathematics seems rather dubious. Weren't they designed for precisely that? And why is typesetting sin etc. a problem? Isn't that almost as straightforward as it gets? Why is `\sin` a problem? Note that I have no idea about MathJax. As already pointed out, that's a distinct issue and off-topic here.

Comment: I don't know very much (anything) about category theory, but it's very hard to see why LaTeX would have trouble with category theory.

Comment: in fact, @au101, the folks at [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage) would be very surprised to learn that LaTeX has trouble with category theory...